# ServerSide code didn´t work and it's too slow

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have this serverside code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    JSONArray back = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    int rows = 0;
    try {       
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/onecheck","****","****");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT id,category,bDay FROM people LIMIT 100000");

        while(rs.next())
        {
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
            array.add(rs.getString("UID"));
            array.add(rs.getString("Kategorie"));
            array.add(rs.getString("Geburtsdatum"));
            rows++;
            back.add(array);

        }
        object.put("draw", 3);
        object.put("recordsTotal", rows);
        object.put("recordsFiltered", rows);
        object.put("data", back);
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        out.print(object);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and here is my table, run on a testing server:

```
http://148.251.42.116:8080/oneCheck/
```

(please have a look at the website source code)

The problem is:

1. The whole entries are showing just on one site, as you can see.
2. The loading from the entries is too slow (in this example are using just 60,000 entries, because the whole database is about 350,000).
3. If I type some kind of word into the searching field, the site is freezing (if I don't use `serverSide`).

So what's the problem?

Many thanks.

Comment: There's no problem. You shouldnt rely on js capabilities on searching and sorting in large data.

Comment: What do u mean @BatuZet?

Comment: Loading is not the problem here but the preparing and showing a table which has 10000 records for js. For displaying such a table; taking so much time and screen freezing is perfectly normal.

Comment: But not all in just one site.

Comment: agree with @Batu Zet, what do you expect? 60.000 rows which datatables  need to process and insert into the DOM? An unofficiel rule / my estimate) is about is about 4-5000 rows top. What you get with sorting, filtering and so on, you loose in initialization speed.

Comment: i have heard the datatables can easy handel millions of rows?!

Comment: How should that happend? jQuery dataTables cannot do anything faster than any other javascript, and is inhibited (read : even more slow) by the use of jQuery. "Millions of records" is serverside processing only, see http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side -> jQuery dataTables would never be able to handle millions of records clientside.

Comment: So should i solved it with PHP?

Comment: Now i have set the LIMIT of the SQL statement to 100(see at http://148.251.42.116:8080/employee/) But still - all rows are shown just at one site - no filtering, no pagination oO

Comment: i need the solution- PLEASE